# Search Historically-Featured Questions

Tags: feature-request, search

Today I ran into an issue with a program I'm writing. I specifically remember seeing a featured question several months ago on SO that addressed my specific issue, but after a decent search via Google/SO I can't seem to find it.

This got me thinking, has there been any consideration given to a search option for featured questions? It would certainly be easier to sift through several dozen questions rather than searching all questions. Maybe there's a way to do this already that I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not what you had in mind, but the work around is to notice that all the historically locked questions are on [the Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) and in the data dumps.

A side effect of that is that the team is unlikely to consider live searches high priority.

Have the historically locked material in the live searches by default is counter indicated because we don't want new users finding that stuff and saying *"Aha! Now I know what good content looks like!"* And yes, there is a great big banner saying not to take this stuff as indicative of current judgement, but we all know that (all together now) *Users Don't Read*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You're right, that's not what I had in mind. But it sounds like there may be a way using the Data Explorer. You wouldn't happen to know the id for questions that have been featured, do you?

Comment: "Have the historically locked material": [http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=locked%3Ayes](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=locked%3Ayes)

Answer (score 1):

A [Google search](https://www.google.com/#q=site:stackoverflow.com+-site:meta.stackoverflow.com+%22This+question+exists+because+it+has+historical+significance%22) for

```
site:stackoverflow.com -site:meta.stackoverflow.com "This question exists because it has historical significance"
```

should net you the questions on Stack Overflow that are displaying the "historical lock" message.